# Is it grammatical to use “lucid dream” as a verb?

Tags: verbs, compounds

[This page](https://www.wikihow.com/Lucid-Dream) has “How to Lucid Dream” in a title. “Lucid” is an adjective, shouldn't we use an adverb as in “to dream lucidly”, or a hyphen as in “to lucid-dream”? Or is it acceptable because sufficiently widespread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's acceptable, as evidenced by its use on the site you link to.

The phrase "lucid dream" is an idiom, because its meaning cannot be understood from the meaning of "lucid" (expressed clearly; easy to understand). It is reasonable that the noun idiom "lucid dream" can be used as a verb "to lucid-dream".

Compound verbs like this tend to be rarer than compound nouns, but compound verbs can be formed from existing compound nouns.  There are already compound verbs based on "dream", such as "to daydream".